# run bash with php to purge cloudflare

Tags: php, bash

im trying to purge single url on cloudflare , 
this is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 http://your.domain.com/url"
    exit 0
fi
#get this from Account section in Cloudflare
TOKEN="SECRETTOKEN"
EMAIL="EMAIL"
DOMAIN="DOMAIN"

curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html \
  -d "a=zone_file_purge" \
  -d "tkn=$TOKEN" \
  -d "email=$EMAIL" \
  -d "z=$DOMAIN" \
  -d "url=$1" >> test.log #output to check if this script work
```

and my php script

```
<?php
$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
$actual_link = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];
exec("/bin/bash /path/to/bkl.sh $actual_link");
echo "Success";
header('Refresh: 5; URL=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

**method** : i put a button on my website , so when user click on that button it will execute bash script on the server and purge the post url on cloudflare , and after that visitor will be redirect back to the post.

when i manually test bash script in my ssh it work perfectly and the test.log has result "SUCCESS"

but when i run php script on my website the test.log does not generate any output which mean its fail.

thank you hope someone can give me a better solution.

Comment: Use the 2nd and 3rd optional parameters to exec() to find out about the error encountered.

Comment: sorry i dont understand mate , can you give example ? sorry my php knowledge is limited

Comment: When you run the example in an SSH session, you manually form the command line including the arguments you pass to the script. When calling from PHP it is dynamically assembled. You need to focus on what is different in the latter case. Using the 2nd parameter to exec() allows you to examine the output from the script execution. Using the 3rd parameter you can learn the return code (exit value) of the script execution. Both can be useful to find out what's going wrong. `exec("/bin/bash /path/to/bkl.sh $actual_link", $output, $returnCode)` then `var_dump($returnCode, $output)`

Comment: ok tested it and the output is int(0) array(0) { } , i guess it failed right ?